# segmentation fault in pdl2 with some code from my .perldlrc that works OK directly from the pdl2 shell

Tags: perl, read-eval-print-loop, pdl

combining

[Is there an equivalent to the perl debugger 'x' in pdl2 (or Devel::REPL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898558/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-perl-debugger-x-in-pdl2-or-develrepl)

and

[How can I list all variables that are in a given scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747521/how-can-i-list-all-variables-that-are-in-a-given-scope/748510#748510)

I have created my perldlrc like

```
use feature ':5.10';
use Data::Dumper;
use PadWalker qw/peek_our peek_my/;


sub x {
  my $depth = shift||0;

  $Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = $depth;
  print Data::Dumper->Dump([@_])
}


sub lvars {
    my $vars = in_scope_variables();

    print Dumper [keys %$vars];
}

sub in_scope_variables {
    my %in_scope = %{peek_our(1)};
    my $lexical  = peek_my(1);
    for my $name (keys %main::) {
        my $glob = $main::{$name};
        if (defined ${$glob}) {
            $in_scope{'$' . $name} = ${$glob};
        }

        if ( @{$glob}) {
            $in_scope{'@' . $name} = [@{$glob}];
        }

        if (%{$glob}) {
            $in_scope{'%' . $name} = {%{$glob}};
        }
    }

    #lexicals hide package variables
    while (my ($var, $ref) = each %$lexical) {
        $in_scope{$var} = $ref;
    }
    return \%in_scope;
}
```

Then I start pdl2 but the methods do not work:

```
$ pdl2
pdl> $xx=in_scope_variables()
Runtime error: You can't FIRSTKEY with the %~ hash at (eval 254) line 38

pdl> lvars
Segmentation fault
```

If I commented the loop

```
# for my $name (keys %main::) {
#     [...]
# }
```

Then only lvars fail:

```
pdl> $xx=in_scope_variables()
pdl> lvars                   
Segmentation fault
```

But if I run the code directly in the pdl2 shell it works

```
pdl> $xx=in_scope_variables()
pdl> x 1, $xx        
$VAR1 = {
          '$_REPL' => 'REF(0x19999708)'
        };
pdl> print Dumper [keys %$xx];  
$VAR1 = [
          '$_REPL'
        ];
```

Do someone have any idea why this two errors happens?

Is that a pdl2 problem a Devel::REPL problem or me doing something stupid?

I am using perl 5.12 and Perldl2 Shell v0.005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SOLVED the segmentation fault:

I have updated my one year old PadWalker version and now with the 
PadWalker-1.92 it works ok.

Unfortunately I didn't write down my version before updating, so I can not report with which version I had problems.

- Still pending the error in the capture of the `%main::` variables:

  Runtime error: You can't FIRSTKEY with the %~ hash at (eval 254) line 38